# $q promise from function not getting its value propagated into the Angular view when resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

For some reason, when I return a `$q` promise from a scope function, the value never gets propagated on resolution:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve("hello");
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    $scope.promiseReturn = function() {
        return promise;
    };
});
```

And the view:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>promiseReturn: {{promiseReturn()}}</p>
</body>
```

[Here's a Plunker for this code](http://plnkr.co/edit/79F80uU9LmyMGxuchfph?p=preview). The view ends up looking like:

```
promiseReturn: {}
```

My understanding seemed to be that the templating engine would deal with `$q` promises fairly transparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`$q` promises can be attached to the scope directly**, and when resolved, their value will be cause the view to be updated (and their resolved value will be used), but they **cannot be the return value of a scope function**.

If you return a promise from a function on a scope, the return value is used as-is. A promise looks like an object `{then: function() { ... }}`, and Angular's JSON serialiser ignores keys with function values, so you just get `{}` in the view. [Here's a Plunker demonstrating this](http://plnkr.co/edit/yrJO6YPNzkOFXrsW1Hlp?p=preview).

Angular deals with this in a few locations; you can see some in [parse.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js) (search for `.then`).

Comment: "but they cannot be the return value of a scope function": that was exactly what I did wrong... Thx!

Comment: @Wilt: glad this was useful to you. :)